# "error in nc_open trying to open file" when calling raster()

Tags: r, raster

```
#Crop Vietnam
lst <- raster(destPath, varname = 'tbb_14')
lst_crop <- crop(lst, ext_VN)
lst_crop <- lst_crop - 273.15

#Write output raster
outFilename <- paste(substr(j,1, nchar(j)-15),'_tbb_14.tif', sep='')
writeRaster(lst_crop, paste(extractedFolder + '/tbb_14/', outFilename, sep=""))
```

How should I fix the problem? I've tried to change path, grant permission for user, diving on the Internet to find a way, but there was nothing solved

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please copy/paste the relevant messages in a form of text. Images should be reserved to convey information that cannot be conveyed in any other way.

Comment: There is no file by that name in that location, as is clearly stated in the rest of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You do this

```
lst <- raster(destPath, varname = 'tbb_14')
```

That fails, suggesting that `destPath` does not exist. You can see for yourself with

```
file.exists(destPath)
```

Once you have the correct filename, you can also replace "raster" with "terra", like this

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(destPath, 'tbb_14')
```